# R fromJSON cannot open the connection

Tags: json, r, web-services

I am working with an algorithm R that calls a webservice that makes a query to a database and returns a JSON object.

```
url <- paste ('https://example.com?id=1'') 
document <- fromJSON (content = url, method = 'C')
```

On my machine the algorithm usually works bad when I go up to the server and run, I get the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: fromJSON -> fromJSON -> I -> structure -> unique
Execution halted
```

There is some problem for the url be https?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors like `cannot open the connection` often mean that the file doesn't exist, or you don't have privileges to read it.

You don't say whether you are using the `rjson` or `RJSONIO` package, but since you included a `method` argument, I'm guessing that it's the former.  `rjson::fromJSON` treats its first argument as a string of JSON. You should be using the `file` argument instead.

```
document <- fromJSON(file = url)
```

As a matter of best practice, when parsing content from the internet you should download it first; then parse it (in two separate steps).  That way, when something goes wrong and an error is thrown, you don't use up bandwidth redownloading it.

Try splitting your code up into:

```
json_file <- "path/to/save/it/to/the_data.json"
download.file(url, json_file)
document <- fromJSON(file = json_file)
```

---

Note that `download.file` doesn't support `https` by default.  Under Windows, you can do `setInternet2()` to use Internet Explorer's connection DLL, and then it works.  See the Details section of `?download.file`.

Comment: Using your code, I get the error in the command by download.file 
Error in download.file (url, json_file): unsupported URL scheme