# Accessing JSON Objects in R

Tags: json, r

I've been trying to access an API, which appears in the following JSON format:

> {"notes":"data is an array of arrays (rows), column names for rows in
>   row_headers","row_headers":["Date","Time Spent (seconds)","Number of
>   People","Activity","Category","Productivity"],"rows":[["2014-05-28T09:00:00",538,1,"Gmail","Email",-1],["2014-05-28T09:00:00",450,1,"MS
>   Outlook","Email",1],["2014-05-28T09:00:00",374,1,"communicator","General
>   Communication \u0026 Scheduling",1],["2014-05-28T09:00:00",315,1,"MS
>   Terminal Services Client","General Software
>   Development",2],["2014-05-28T09:00:00",306,1,"fivethirtyeight.com","General
>   News \u0026 Opinion",-

I was able to import this JSON dictionary with Python and cast it into a dataframe using the following code:

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data['rows'],columns=data['row_headers'])
```

However, when I try to do a similar thing in R with the following code, I get an error saying that R "cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory."

```
json_file <- 'url of API key'
raw_json <- fromJSON(file=json_file['raw'])
```

If anyone has any insight into how you can go about loading a JSON object like I show above into an R dataframe, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `json_file['raw']` returns `NA`. WHat are you trying to do with the `"raw"` index. (This isn't how R works)

Comment: I was trying to access the data which the notes say is in an array of arrays called list.

Comment: but in your example, json_file is a character string denoting the file name...

Comment: Let me clarify: in the first code box you can see a JSON library which has some notes. In the notes, it says that the data is in an array or arrays (rows) and that the column names for rows is "row_headers". I'm just trying to access the raw data (and would also like the row headers as column names).

Comment: Yes, json_file is a string containing the URL; however, when that is inserted inside the arguments fromJSON(file=json_file) I was under the impression that it pulled the JSON object from the URL i specified.

Comment: That isn't how `R` works (in general). `json_file['raw']` will be evaluated and then passed to `fromJSON`, in which case you will be effectively calling `fromJSON(file=NA)`. try `raw_json <- fromJSON(file=json_file)`, and then proceeding from there. Without a reproducible example, there isn't much else to suggest.

Comment: Ok, so I tried that and ran into an error saying that it was an unsupported URL scheme. Using the following API key I just created might help "https://www.rescuetime.com/anapi/data?rtapi_key=B63NUgr1wbXQS_I6tT8ON0LpvyPPcXNOd1mXfrG9&perspective=interval&format=json&resolution_time=hour&restrict_kind=activity&restrict_begin=2013-01-01&restrict_end=2014-08-28"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works using `RJSONIO::fromJSON`

```
library(RJSONIO)

raw_json <- fromJSON(content = "https://www.rescuetime.com/anapi/data?rtapi_key=B63NUgr1wbXQS_I6tT8ON0LpvyPPcXNOd1mXfrG9&perspective=interval&format=json&resolution_time=hour&restrict_kind=activity&restrict_begin=2013-01-01&restrict_end=2014-08-28%22")
```

You can then use `data.table::rbindlist` to coerce to a `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
final_data <- rbindlist(lapply(raw_json[['rows']],setattr,'names', raw_json[['row_headers']]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still running into the issue that when I try to access the https, I get an error saying that R "cannot open the connection." I saw the Stack thread about this issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852742/r-fromjson-cannot-open-the-connection), and was still unable to import the content. Do you have any suggestions for how to go about doing this?